# How to get var value to use in this id?

Tags: javascript, php

How to get var value to use in this id ?

After split var `love_id`, i want to get var `id2` value to use in id how to do that ?

```
id="<?php echo var id2; ?>
```

eg : var id2 = 24

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.like',function(){        
      var love_id = $(this).attr('id');
      var love_id_after_ex = love_id.split('-');
      var id1 = love_id_after_ex[0], id2 = love_id_after_ex[1];

      var postData = 'id1='+id1+'&user=yes';
      $.ajax({      
        type: "POST",
        url: "xxxxxx.php",
        data: postData,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){
          $('#'+love_id).append('<a class="unlike" style=" cursor: pointer; " id="<?php echo var id2; ?>">yessssssss</a>');
        }       
      });
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Except `love` and `ex` I didn't understand a thing in this question and those two automatically split mostly ;)

Comment: eg. i get var id2 = 24, i want to use var id2 in id tag , how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the line you want is:

```
$('#'+love_id).append('<a class="unlike" style=" cursor: pointer; " id="' + id2 +'">yessssssss</a>');
```

Comment: it's work thank, but split function that i use , can not split ?  can do you rewrite for me ?

Comment: what is the current id that you have in the html ?